# abinitio decimal to floating conversion

Tags: type-conversion, ab-initio

In abinitio I have a code like below. Both divisior and denominator are decimals. In my example, when 1 is divided by 2 , the result is 0. However I want it to be like 0.50. How can I achieve this ? I tried several castings but it didn't work.

```
count(in.bad_video_experience_grid_div)/ 
if( count(in.bad_video_experience_grid_dnm)==0)(1)
else count(in.bad_video_experience_grid_dnm))
```

Comment: Maybe precede the expression by `1.0 * `,  possibly with `(...)` so not Integer division is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've multipled the divisor by 1.0 and the denominator by 1.0 , then it worked.